# Creation of a Google Maps clone

Tags: javascript, api, maps, react

Good morning,
I want to ask you some suggestions to create an application that basically is able to replicate Google Maps using Here APIs.

My principal purpose is to display a map and a polyline that indicates the route between my actual position and a specified location. This map must be updated frequenty according to the actual position on the car.

Any idea of a guideline to follow? I'm completely new to the world of programming an application like that, but from what I've found a good solution can be to use Javascript or React.

Comment: You could use [openstreetmap.org](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=10/51.4707/-0.0158), it already has an [API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely dive deeper into the documentation (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/implementing-route.html) if you do advanced calculations like this. And better to ask those questions on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ rather than here.
Talking about the actual (react) app and what to utilize is quite a broad topic. Here service offers some [overview](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.42.0/dev_guide/topics/react-practices.html), which should kick-start you however without proper react introduction, you are missing a lot.